# How can I keep python from truncating large numbers after division

Tags: python-3.3, largenumber

I am trying to do division with very large numbers. I know that python can handle them before the division, but is there a way to keep python from truncating the answer?

an example follows:

> > > s = 
> > >       68729682406644277238837486231747530924247154108646671752192618583088487405790957964732883069102561043436779663935595172042357306594916344606074564712868078287608055203024658359439017580883910978666185875717415541084494926500475167381168505927378181899753839260609452265365274850901879881203714
> > >
> > > M = 
> > >       2047
> > >
> > > s/(2*M) = 1.6787904837968803e+289

It can remember the 292 digit number s but when it divides the large number it gets truncated.

Is there any way that I can get an exact answer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned with the *integer* part of the answer, you can use `//` which is the integer division operator:

```
s // (2*M)
```

It looks like your `s` is a multiple of `M` so it sounds like this is what you are looking for.

In Python (3 and later), the `/` operator is the *floating point* division operator, while `//` is the *integer* division operator. Previous versions of Python had only `/` and would do different things depending on whether the operands were both integers or not. This was confusing, so a new `//` operator was introduced and `/` was redefined to be always floating point.

Comment: Sorry ran into another problem, I need it to keep some decimals as well. I don't want it to just round at the decimal place otherwise I cant tell if a number is a factor or not. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Well, you could multiply the result and the divisor back together to see whether it equals the original dividend. Or, you could use `%` and see whether the remainder is 0 or not.

Comment: That's what I have been doing, I am just looking at cleaning up some code now.